# How to extract the year via regex from a string in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to extract the year from a string with this format:

```rb
dataset_name = 'ALTVALLEDAOSTA000020191001.json'
```

I tried:

```rb
dataset_name[/<\b(19|20)\d{2}\b>/, 1]
/\b(19|20)\d{2}\b/.match(dataset_name)
```

I'm still reading the docs but so far I'm not able to achieve the result I want. I'm really bad at regex.

Comment: What if it were `'ALTVALLEDAOSTA000010012019.json'`?

Comment: Is the year always 4 digits from the `.json`?  Or can it be anywhere in the string?

Comment: The format spec is unclear. I can only assume `yyyymmdd.json` is fixed, in which case you can use `s[-13...-9]`. Is this sufficient or is there more to the format spec than implied by this example?

Comment: @ggorlen that sounds reasonable!

Comment: @CarySwoveland  and Mark thanks for the pointers, the names are generated by another service but I guess the year position should be pretty static

Comment: This regex works in that case: `(\d{4})\d{4}\.`

Comment: You need to edit your question to clarify it. At the beginning state the *rule* for determining where the date is located in the string. When you given an example you should *always* state the desired result. I suggest you give a couple of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your dataset name always ends in `yyyymmdd.json`, you can take a slice of the last 13-9 characters counting from the rear:

```
irb(main):001:0> dataset_name = 'ALTVALLEDAOSTA000020191001.json'
irb(main):002:0> dataset_name[-13...-9]
=> "2019"
```

You can also use a regex if you want a bit more precision:

```
irb(main):003:0> dataset_name =~ /(\d{4})\d{4}\.json$/
=> 18
irb(main):004:0> $1
=> "2019"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get to Rome.

Starting with:

```
foo = 'ALTVALLEDAOSTA000020191001.json'
```

Stripping the extended filename + extension to its [`basename`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/File.html#method-c-basename) then using a regex:

```
ymd = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/
ext = File.extname(foo)
File.basename(foo, ext) # => "ALTVALLEDAOSTA000020191001"

File.basename(foo, ext)[ymd, 1] # => "2019"
File.basename(foo, ext)[ymd, 2] # => "10"
File.basename(foo, ext)[ymd, 3] # => "01"
```

Using a regex against the entire filename to grab just the year:

```
ymd = /^.*(\d{4})/
foo[ymd, 1] # => "1001"
```

or extracting the year, month and day:

```
ymd = /^.*(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/
foo[ymd, 1] # => "2019"
foo[ymd, 2] # => "10"
foo[ymd, 3] # => "01"
```

Using String's [`unpack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-unpack):

```
ymd = '@18A4'
foo.unpack(ymd)  # => ["2019"]
```

or:

```
ymd = '@18A4A2A2'
foo.unpack(ymd)  # => ["2019", "10", "01"]
```

If the strings are consistent length and format, then I'd work with [`unpack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-unpack), because, if I remember right, it is the fastest, followed by String slicing, with anchored, then unanchored regular expressions trailing.